# What is an empirical proof that two concepts are not independent/orthogonal?

Tags: terminology, experimental-psychology, experiment-design

Given there are two psychological concepts A and B that are considered to be independent/orthogonal.

Would the following empirical results proof the opposite? If not why?

In the first experiment A is the independent variable with two conditions: high and low A.
B is identically induced in both conditions and measured as the dependent variable.
In the high A condition high B is measured. In the low A condition low B is measured.
The second experiment is analog to the first one, except with A and B reversed: in the high B condition high A is measured, and in the low B condition low A is measured.

References to papers that use similiar arguments would be very helpful.

Comment: This might be [more suitable on statistics SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com)? I see no direct necessary relation to this site.

Comment: The questions is about the interpretation of such empirical results in the context of cognitive science research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the data show a two-way dependence (low A -> low B, hi A -> hi B and the reverse) this would prove the variables are not independent, as

> Linearly independent, orthogonal, and uncorrelated are three terms used to indicate lack of relationship between variables.

<sub>**Reference**

**-** [Rodgers *et al.*, The American Statistician (1984); **38**(2): 133-4](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/254330622_Linearly_Independent_Orthogonal_and_Uncorrelated_Variables)</sub>

Comment: Thank you for your answer! One follow up question: What can be derived from such a two-way dependence? Might one even say A and B are essentially the same?

Comment: @thando My pleasure. They are likely not the same, as no numerical values are given

Comment: You need to be very careful with the interpretation of non-independence though. Ultimately everything is non-independent (because you can intervene with a brick and send performance on every task to zero, followed by very highly correlated recovery of all abilities). [non]orthogonality is a stronger claim and correspondingly harder to demonstrate. You might want to explore "systems factorial technology" or "Signed difference analysis".

Comment: Thank you @steveLangsford, also for the hints! What would be reasonable hypotheses about the relation of the two concepts, given the experimental results in the question above?

Comment: From a strict logic perspective the description leaves a pretty wide field of possible relationships still feasible. But presumably there's a lot more constraining information contained in how A and B are supposed to work and the manipulation that was used to fix their levels?

Comment: Thank you very much! I posted a [separate question](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/20785/how-can-two-way-dependencies-in-factorial-designs-be-interpreted) about this concern. There is no model about how A and B interact.